# Can I use Google's old engine?

Tags: google-search

I've heard Google is using a new engine (Panda or something like that I think?), and I have definitively noticed over the past few months that Google has tried to be more clever when I search.

However more often than not its attempt to be more clever than me (by showing me mainly results to what it think I ought to have searched for instead of what I actually searched for) is both counter productive and highly frustrating.

Is there a way to make it behave like it used to or is it time to resort to using another search engine?

I could search for exact phrase I know by using quotes, but that isn't usually what I want either, I just want it to search for the exact words, not the exact phrase.

Comment: You have no control over google in this capacity

Answer (score 1):

Using quotation marks (even if only around one word) helps it do things more literally.  It certainly won't get you results using the old engine, but it will stop interpreting the context as "intelligently".

Yes, you get a different result set most of the time when quoting a single word, for example searching for *"beanbag"* instead of *beanbag*.

Quoting multiple words together forces the string to appear as-is (not including punctuation as google ignores special characters).

For example, searching for the rather strange phrase  *"Need money for more money"* (that I saw a homeless person showing on a cardboard sign once) only shows two results (and I'm sure this superuser page will show up soon enough) whereas searching for *Need money for more money* without quotes shows several million.